# How to pass id as query string in asp.net mvc 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, routes

I want to route a URL like `http://localhost:8888/api/orders?id=1`
to an action, but it only works when the URL is given in this format: `http://localhost:8888/api/orders/1`

Two actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get(bool includeItems=true)
{            
        var results = _repository.GetAllOrders(includeItems);

        return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Order>, IEnumerable<OrderViewModel>>(results));

}

[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{            
        var order = _repository.GetOrderById(id);

        if (order != null)                
            return Ok(_mapper.Map<Order, OrderViewModel>(order));               
        else                
            return NotFound();                         
}
```

It works fine if I send a URL like:
`http://localhost:8888/api/orders?includeItems=false`.

When I send the URL `http://localhost:8888/api/orders?id=1`, it gets mapped to the first Action which has `includeItems` as parameter.
I have `[Route("api/[Controller]")]` attribute on top of my controller.

Comment: I think you should try to add  [FromQuery] to your Get action, like public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] int id).

Comment: But I think another approach is to add another MapRoute call with the necessary route template. The default route template that everyone typically starts with is /Controller/Action/{?id}.

Comment: This post suggests to make the parameter optional. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797617/route-to-allow-a-parameter-from-both-query-string-and-default-id-template

Comment: I tried both [FormQuery] attribute and following code: 
[HttpGet("{id:int?}")] public IActionResult Get(int id=0) { //Code }, both didnt work :(

Comment: still looking for answer ?

Comment: yes, I tried the above suggestions, none of them worked.